# Second level in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having some problem with creating a "second level" of CheckedListBox.

Example :

Here is my CheckedListBox :

[image]

Code for this :

```
 checkedListBox_materiałyDoRozliczenia.DataSource = dataTableMaterials;
 checkedListBox_materiałyDoRozliczenia.DisplayMember = "material";
```

To do that this way I'm binding dataTable as DataSource of checkedListBox.

What I'm trying to accomplish is something like that :

[image]

As you can see, there is "second level".
When the element will be checked i want this "second level" to appear. DataSource for this "second level" will be another DataTable.

Can you help me accomplish this?

Is it even possible to do it?

Comment: Have you thought of a `TreeView` instead of a `CheckedListBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is called a "TreeView".
A treeview looks like this:
[image]

You just want to add checkboxes to the children (items in a tree view).
There is an excellent piece of [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes(v=vs.110).aspx) for this, or an [asp.net youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OCcU4m03Hs).

Codeproject also has an [interactive demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59514/Simple-Tri-State-TreeView) which includes the source code.